# Why am I getting old value of state in the setState callback in react.js

Tags: reactjs

- I have a function to update the state and call another function to
  update object value in the setState callback method.
- I also added a debugger on the breakpoint for the setState callback
  method, what I observe is that the value always is the old one.

```
updateContactPath(path, index) {
    const { contactPaths } = this.state;
    const { setFieldValue } = this.props;
    contactPaths[index] = path;
    this.setState(
      {
        contactPaths,
      },
      () => setFieldValue('contactPaths', contactPaths),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Comment: You mutate the `contactPaths` array but then setState with the same old array reference. You need to setState with a new array object which involves copying the old array *then* mutating the index with the new path.

Comment: @DrewReese I don't think so. Actually, line 7, I can get the latest contactPaths, but line 9, the contactPaths in the callback function is the old values.

Comment: @DrewReese you mean like this?
```
updateContactPath(path, index) {
    const { contactPaths } = this.state;
    const { setFieldValue } = this.props;
    const updatedContactPaths = [...contactPaths];
    updatedContactPaths[index] = path;
    this.setState(
      {
        contactPaths,
      },
      () => setFieldValue('contactPaths', updatedContactPaths),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Don't mutate state, create a new copy, edit it then set that to new state. Or just create a new one directly in the `setState` call. Something like `this.setState({ contactPaths: contactPaths.map((p,i) => index === i ? path : p)})` and finally, in the callback log `this.state.contactPaths`

Comment: Yes, it is the old (current) value of `contactPaths` which you destructured from state and is saved in the enclosure of your function. If you want the new `contactPaths` state value then in the setState callback you need to access it via `this.state.contactPaths`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like this to ensure updated state -:

```
updateContactPath(path, index) {
    const { contactPaths } = this.state;
    const { setFieldValue } = this.props;
    this.setState(
      {
        [...contactPaths, [index]: path],
      },
      () => setFieldValue('contactPaths', this.state.contactPaths),
    );
  }
```